# RMAN-05579: CONTROLFILE buckup not found при восстановлении БД из Бэкапа

Tags: oracle, администрирование, rman

У меня есть бэкап, созданный с помощью RMAN.
Скрипт:

```
connect target /
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
run{
allocate channel d1 type disk;
backup full format 'D:\Databases\Backups\02.RMAN_BKP\bkp__%d_%U.bus'
database;
}
startup;
exit;
```

Вывод:

```
connected to target database: DO_ETLN (DBID=4267723674)

using target database control file instead of recovery catalog
database closed
database dismounted
Oracle instance shut down

connected to target database (not started)
Oracle instance started
database mounted

Total System Global Area    2254802944 bytes

Fixed Size                     2283224 bytes
Variable Size                587204904 bytes
Database Buffers            1644167168 bytes
Redo Buffers                  21147648 bytes

allocated channel: d1
channel d1: SID=63 device type=DISK

Starting backup at 18-SEP-18
channel d1: starting full datafile backup set
channel d1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
input datafile file number=00004 name=D:\DATABASES\DO_ETLN\BD\USERS01.DBF
input datafile file number=00005 name=D:\DATABASES\DO_ETLN\BD\INDEXES01.DBF
input datafile file number=00002 name=D:\DATABASES\DO_ETLN\BD\SYSAUX01.DBF
input datafile file number=00001 name=D:\DATABASES\DO_ETLN\BD\SYSTEM01.DBF
input datafile file number=00003 name=D:\DATABASES\DO_ETLN\BD\UNDOTBS01.DBF
input datafile file number=00006 name=D:\DATABASES\DO_ETLN\BD\LOB_TS_01.DBF
input datafile file number=00007 name=D:\DATABASES\DO_ETLN\BD\REPOSITORY_BO_01.DBF
input datafile file number=00008 name=D:\DATABASES\DO_ETLN\BD\TOOLS_01.DBF
channel d1: starting piece 1 at 18-SEP-18
channel d1: finished piece 1 at 18-SEP-18
piece handle=D:\DATABASES\BACKUPS\02.RMAN_BKP\BKP__DO_ETLN_01TDECMD_1_1.BUS tag=TAG20180918T170933 comment=NONE
channel d1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:01:05
channel d1: starting full datafile backup set
channel d1: specifying datafile(s) in backup set
including current control file in backup set
including current SPFILE in backup set
channel d1: starting piece 1 at 18-SEP-18
channel d1: finished piece 1 at 18-SEP-18
piece handle=D:\DATABASES\BACKUPS\02.RMAN_BKP\BKP__DO_ETLN_02TDECOF_1_1.BUS tag=TAG20180918T170933 comment=NONE
channel d1: backup set complete, elapsed time: 00:00:01
Finished backup at 18-SEP-18
released channel: d1

database is already started
database opened

Recovery Manager complete.
```

Я пытаюсь его восстановить во вновь созданную БД.
Скрипт:

```
connect auxiliary / 
run{ 
allocate auxiliary channel aux1 device type disk;
allocate auxiliary channel aux2 device type disk;
allocate auxiliary channel aux3 device type disk;
allocate auxiliary channel aux4 device type disk;
SET NEWNAME FOR DATABASE TO 'D:\Databases\DODEVT\%b'; 
DUPLICATE TARGET DATABASE TO DODEVT
backup location '"D:\Databases\Backups\02.RMAN_BKP"' NOREDO
logfile
   group 1 ('D:\Databases\DODEVT\redo01.log') size 50M reuse,
   group 2 ('D:\Databases\DODEVT\redo02.log') size 50M reuse,
   group 3 ('D:\Databases\DODEVT\redo03.log') size 50M reuse;
}
exit;
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
connected to auxiliary database: DODEVT2 (not mounted)

allocated channel: aux1
channel aux1: SID=63 device type=DISK

allocated channel: aux2
channel aux2: SID=129 device type=DISK

allocated channel: aux3
channel aux3: SID=193 device type=DISK

allocated channel: aux4
channel aux4: SID=6 device type=DISK

executing command: SET NEWNAME

Starting Duplicate Db at 18-SEP-18
released channel: aux1
released channel: aux2
released channel: aux3
released channel: aux4
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-00569: =============== ERROR MESSAGE STACK FOLLOWS ===============
RMAN-00571: ===========================================================
RMAN-03002: failure of Duplicate Db command at 09/18/2018 17:11:47
RMAN-05501: aborting duplication of target database
RMAN-05579: CONTROLFILE backup not found in "D:\Databases\Backups\02.RMAN_BKP"

Recovery Manager complete.
db dublicated
```

Вроде как контрольный файл содержится в моем бэкапе, но RMAN говорит, что его нет.
Подскажите, что я упустил?

Comment: кроме backup database надо делать отдельно `backup current controlfile`

Comment: Мне не очень понятно почему, если я в логе вижу строку `including current control file in backup set`. У меня `backup full`.

Comment: хм. действительно странно. во всякой документации встречал, что контролфайл почему то бекапят отдельно, почему отдельно не задумывался

Comment: Возможно я должен включить что-то еще?(кроме Archivelogmode ?). Или как то указать явно в команде дубликата путь к контрольному файлы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что мой скрипт генерации дописал мне двойные кавычки к пути, а RMAN вместо ошибочного пути говорил мне, что по такому пути просто нет контрольного файла.

Было:

```
backup location '"D:\Databases\Backups\02.RMAN_BKP"' NOREDO
```

Должно быть:

```
backup location 'D:\Databases\Backups\02.RMAN_BKP' NOREDO
```

Comment: чем скрипт генерировали?

Comment: bat файл обычный)

Comment: то понятно что через bat, я неправильно интерпретировал Вашу фразу "...что мой скрипт генерации ..."

Comment: У меня bat генерис скрипты для rman'a. А потом их же запускает

Comment: круто, такого еще никогда не видел

Comment: это скорее костыль, для хранения истории. Можно было просто передавать параметры в скрипт Рмана и все, а логи сделать более разумно, но мне было лень

Comment: у меня таким образом и работает, а лог ведется .txt